# Why does Quarkus/Microprofile rest client Response.getEntity() return null?

Tags: quarkus, microprofile, quarkus-rest-client

using `Quarkus 3.0.3 Final`

I have the following rest client declaration:

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="my-api")
@RegisterProvider(value = ErrorMapper.class, priority = 50)
public interface SubscriberClient {
    @POST
    @Path("/v1")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    MyResponse create(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String bearer, MyRequest request);
}
```

I also have in the error mapper.

```
private String getBody(Response response) throws IOException {

  response.getStringHeaders().forEach((s, strings) -> logger.info(s + ": " + strings.toString()));

  // YES I KNOW THIS CAN BE HANDLED BETTER WITH INSTANCEOF
  try (ByteArrayInputStream is = (ByteArrayInputStream) response.getEntity()) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(bytes, 0, is.available());
    String body = new String(bytes);
    return body;
  }
}
```

The headers print

```
content-length: [148]
content-type: [application/json]
```

Which leads me to believe there is a body returned, but for what ever reason `response.getEntity()` is returning null and of course the exception is caught as NullPointerException. But the response is supposed to be a Json that I can parse and handle the error code downstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because getEntity() returns only internal Response's entity object, but if you check source code of ResponseImpl you figure out there is also entityStream object.

So you should use an alternative method readEntity() first, for instance

```
var errorText = response.readEntity(String.class);
var errorResponse = objectMapper.readValue(errorText, ExceptionErrorResponse.class);
```

Comment: or maybe there was an idea to use readEntity() first to cache object from inputStream for subsequent retrievals by getEntity()

Comment: I think the behaviour changed between version because in older Quarkus getEntity worked.

Comment: Ok the docs are just confusing... https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#exception-handling Because they seem to suggest that readEntity must be used in a blocking manner if you response is an InputStream. Anyways I added @Blocking and used readEntity(String.class) seems to work.